# Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter

Tags: groovy

I have this error coming from groovy -v.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter

java version =  openjdk version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17 LTS
got that from Microsoft   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/install

Groovy version 4.0.8
got groovy from jfrog.io
apache-groovy-binary-4.0.8.zip  22-01-23 01:00:24

Have set Java_home and Groovy_home.   Both are appended to the path.
C:\Users<Myusername>\dev\languages\apache-groovy-sdk-4.0.8\groovy-4.0.8\bin
groovy was unzipped into this folder.

I was trying to start the use of groovy by checking its version number.

Comment: Seen this error a few times when switching between installations of groovy. But in all cases, setting `GROOVY_HOME` resolved the problem. What are you setting `GROOVY_HOME` to?

Comment: Please update your question with the values you have for `JAVA_HOME` and `GROOVY_HOME`